# Select XML elements based on value

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, linq, select

I have simple XML. I would like to select CASE where Section = "A" by LINQ in VB.NET WindowsForm application. I would appreciate any help. The tips can be in C#. Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <PredefinedText>
        <Section>A</Section>
        <CASE>Case 1A</CASE>
    </PredefinedText>
    <PredefinedText>
        <Section>B</Section>
        <CASE>Case 1B</CASE>
    </PredefinedText>
</data>
```

I have this code, but it doesn't return any records to ComboBox...

```
sSettingsFilePath = "Sections.xml"

Dim xelement As XElement = xelement.Load(sSettingsFilePath)

ComboBox1.DataSource = (From cases In xelement.Elements("PredefinedText") _
                            Select cases.Element("CASE").Value _
                            Where xelement.Element("PredefinedText").Element("Section").Value = "A"
                            Order By Value).ToList()
```

Comment: And what's your issue?

Comment: your xml query returns what you're wanting.

Comment: Hi Maciej and Jonesy. Thank you for your response. The query result is that I get all CASES for all Sections withouth limitation to section "A". I would like to get just "Case 1A".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `xelement` already is `PredefinedText`, so `xelement.Element("PredefinedText").Element("Section").Value` will never return a existing object (There is not child `PredefinedText` of `PredefinedText`). 
So just convert your statement to:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = (From cases In xelement.Elements("PredefinedText") _
                            Select cases.Element("CASE").Value _
                            Where xelement.Element("Section").Value = "A"
                            Order By Value).ToList()
```

Second option which look more user-friendly is to write your code like this:

```
xelement.Elements("PredefinedText")
                .Where(x => x.Element("Section").Value == "A")
                .OrderBy(x=>x.Value);
```

Comment: Hi Garath. Thank you for your solution. It makes sense to me. I've tried your first posted code. I got "Null Reference Exception" on the row with 'Where' statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("fullfilepath.xml");
var qry = xDoc.Root.Descendants("Section")
    .Where(ele=>ele.Element("PredefinedText").Value=="A") //or StartsWith("A") or Contains("A")
    .OrderBy(ele=>ele.Value)
    .ToList();
```

For further information, please see:

[XDocument.Load Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Samples (LINQ to XML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387091.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
sSettingsFilePath = "Sections.xml"
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(new FileStream(sSettingsFilePath, FileMode.Open))
ComboBox1.DataSource = (From x In doc.root.Elements("PredefinedText")
                        Where x.Element("Section").Value = "A"
                        Select x.Element("CASE").Value).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

For selecting the CASE element,

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = xelement
                           .Descendants("PredefinedText")
                           .Where(i => i.Element("Section").Value == "A")
                           .Select(j => j.Element("CASE").Value);
```

Comment: Hi @Siva Charan. This works great if you add .ToList() function. In VB.NET is ComboBox1.DataSource = xelement.Descendants("PredefinedText").Where(Function(i) i.Element("Section").Value = "A").[Select](Function(j) j.Element("CASE").Value).ToList()